# Schematic symbol color fill with Altium NEXUS

Tags: altium, symbol, schematic

I came across a write-up about using [Solder Bridge Jumpers](https://resources.altium.com/p/solder-bridge-jumper-best-practices-pcb-design) in Altium. However, while attempting to make my own, I was unable to recreate the grey filled semi-circles shown in the authors example:

[image]

When making my own, I am able to create the semi-circles using arcs and lines, but can't convert it to a polygon for filling like I'd expected to be able to. Or, I can create a filled ellipse, but can't break and "erase" the center section to achieve the same result:

[image]

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This was done using a [Pie Chart](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-dlg-changepiechartpie-chart-ad?version=17.1), which has been deprecated as of Nexus 2.1.5.

I was able to obtain the symbols from a schematic library included in the Nordic nrf52840 DK [Hardware Design Documentation](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-hardware/nRF5340-DK/Download#infotabs).